# Setting colour of application bar in C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I define my ApplicationBar in code like that:

```
private void BuildApplicationBar()
        {
            // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0.8;
            ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 138, 204, 34);


            // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
            ApplicationBarIconButton CheckInExitAppBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("icons/check_in.png", UriKind.Relative));
            CheckInExitAppBarButton.Text = AppResource.CheckInExit;
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(CheckInExitAppBarButton);
            CheckInExitAppBarButton.Click += new EventHandler(CheckInExitAppBarButton_Click);

        }
```

Atfer that I can see that color of icons changed, but I can't see text under them. When I do this without ApplicationBar.Color I can see both icon + text but in white which doesn't interest me

Comment: Do you want to set the color of Background or Foreground?

Comment: Foreground. With the code above only color of icon changes. But no text visible under.

Comment: Is the text not set or the color not changed? Is AppResource.CheckInExit set properly?

Comment: Hmm look at my code and post, please. Answers are there. Text is set, AppResource is set properly. Just when I want to change foreground colour in C# color of icon changes but text is not visible at all then...

Comment: How many characters is "CheckInExit"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text uses the alpha value of the foreground color, and you're setting it to 0 (transparent). Set it to 255 instead and it'll work:

```
    private void BuildApplicationBar()
    {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
        ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0.8;
        ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 138, 204, 34);


        // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarIconButton CheckInExitAppBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("icons/check_in.png", UriKind.Relative));
        CheckInExitAppBarButton.Text = AppResource.CheckInExit;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(CheckInExitAppBarButton);
        CheckInExitAppBarButton.Click += new EventHandler(CheckInExitAppBarButton_Click);

    }
```